# Why is Android file creation suddenly failing when it worked on Android 11 previously?

Tags: android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

In the last few days, my Android app is suddenly failing to download files from a web server to store in the app. This is the same for all users I have contacted. It was previously working in Android 11, so it's something that has only just changed. It's a (free) niche app for UK glider pilots to process NOTAMS, and has relatively large number of users who I don't want to let down.

The published app uses getExternalFilesDir(null) to return the directory in which to store the downloaded files, with android:requestLegacyExternalStorage set to "true" in the manifest.

I changed getExternalFilesDir(null) to getFilesDir() in Android Studio since that's what I understand should now be used for internal app data files. This returns */data/user/0/(my package name)/files*. I'm running the Pixel 2 API 30 emulator for debugging, and the File Explorer shows that */data/data/(my package name)/files* directory has been created. Everything I've read on here says that this is what is supposed to happen and it should all work. However no file was created when I attempted the download.

I changed android:requestLegacyExternalStorage to "false", and this time a file was created as expected. However it was empty and the download thread was giving an exception "unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@89599f3f".

This is the relevant code in my  DownloadFile class which runs as a separate thread (comments removed for compactness):

```
public class DownloadFile implements Runnable
{
    private String          mUrlString;
    private String          mFileName;
    private CountDownLatch  mLatch;

    public DownloadFile(String urlString, String fileName, CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        mUrlString  = urlString;
        mFileName   = fileName;
        mLatch      = latch;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

// Note for StackOverflow: following is a public static variable defined in the main activity
        Spine.mDownloadStatus = false; 

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(mUrlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.connect();

            File file = new File(Spine.dataDir, mFileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; // used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutput.close();

            Spine.mDownloadStatus = true;
        }

        // catch some possible errors...
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Spine.mErrorString = e.getMessage();
        }

        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        
        // Signal completion
        mLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

I now believe the problem lies with the URL connection, rather than the changes to local file storage access which is what I first thought. Incidentally, if I enter the full URL into my web browser the complete text file is displayed OK, so it's not a problem with the server.

Comment: Have you tried a more modern HTTP client, such as OkHttp?

Comment: No - I have not looked at alternatives at the moment, as I am first trying to understand why it has suddenly stopped working when it was fine up until a few days ago. There's no point in making major changes without understanding what's causing the problem.

Comment: `with android:requestLegacyExternalStorage set to "true" in the manifest.` Works only on an Android 10 device and is not needed for getExternalFilesDir() or getFilesDir().

Comment: `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);` That would be for POST.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Will check out tomorrow (or rather today as looking at my bedside clock it's Monday already :) )

Comment: Does the server send `Content-Length` headers? This can cause okhttp to fail otherwise if connections are being reused.

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been narrowed down to changes to the functionality of the website that hosts the data files to be downloaded. It's been made https secure and they are currently working on further changes.

I temporarily moved the hosting to my own website in Android Studio and everything worked so it's down to those website changes and nothing to do with my code (at least it may need changing later to support the upgrade to the main hosting site).

Thanks to all for responding.

Comment: I forgot to say what the eventual problem was and how it was solved. The security on the hosting site had been increased to use ssl. The solution was to change all URL strings from http to https and to change HttpURLConnection to HttpsURLConnection